# Redirecting only whole lines from serial port to netcat

Tags: serial-port, newlines, netcat

I would like to redirect data from two serial ports over ethernet connection to single port. I've managed to send data, but as serial port data is slow, messages might get corrupted as these does not wait for carriage return of line feed characters in any way.

I've used these commands

```
netcat -p 23000 -u 192.168.1.7 23000 </dev/ttyUSB1&
netcat -p 23000 -u 192.168.1.7 23000 </dev/ttyUSB0&
```

Other end can receive all data, but lines might get corrupted if both ports are receiving at the same time.

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

shows how characters are received one by one.
With following command I've managed to get serial data get printed line by line.

```
while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do echo "${LINE}"; done < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But how can I get the serial data redirected line by line so that probability to corrupt serial data is not so obvious?

I should replace "/dev/ttyUSB0" in following

```
netcat -p 23000 -u 192.168.1.7 23000 </dev/ttyUSB0&
```

with something like this

```
while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do echo "${LINE}"; done < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Or perhaps there is some smart way to handle lines from two sources so that those don't get corrupted.

Edit: I'm using OpenWRT distro on a WiFi router. I've installed Netcat and I'm not sure if socat is available.
Data to be handled is NMEA0183 messages from two devices. I think those have something special only in the beginning of the line.

Comment: Are you willing to change programs, e.g. to use socat instead of netcat? Are there any control characters in the data apart from newline i.e. is this text or binary? Did you try combining your two attempts i.e. `while IFS='' read -r LINE ; do printf '%s\n' "$LINE" ; done | netcat -p 23000 -u 192.168.1.7 23000` to write a line at a time to netcat?

Comment: It seems you are using two different accounts. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge them so you can edit your original post without problems.